# SQL error - not unique table

Tags: sql

Can someone please tell me how to fix this query to have it work so that I do not receive the error message : #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'personal_mem'

```
  SELECT personal_mem.id_mem, personal_mem.fn, personal_mem.ln, personal_mem.email,     personal_mem.organisation, personal_mem.city, personal_mem.state, personal_mem.postcode, members.type, members.paid_to_date, members.username, payments_mem.payment_type 
    FROM `personal_mem`  
    LEFT JOIN personal_mem ON members.id_mem = personal_mem.id_mem 
    LEFT JOIN payments_mem ON members.id_mem = payments_mem.id_mem 
    WHERE members.paid_to_date > 1369922400 AND payments_mem.confirmed != 'TRUE' 
    ORDER BY payments_mem.payment_type
```

Comment: replace `FROM personal_mem` with `FROM members`

Comment: Use different Aliases to join the same table multiple times and where is your `members` table in from clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the `personal_mem` table against itself, so you have it twice in the result, making the column references ambiguous.

This looks like a mistake, since you are also referring to `members`, which is not declared anywhere, you probably wanted to join with that table instead.

```
FROM personal_mem 
LEFT JOIN /**/ members /**/ ON members.id_mem = personal_mem.id_mem
```

or maybe

```
FROM /**/  members  /**/
LEFT JOIN personal_mem ON members.id_mem = personal_mem.id_mem
```

If this is not a mistake, you need to give the table an alias.

Answer (score 0):

You're joining the same table to itself and not aliasing anything. Give the table in the select clause an alias by adding something after the name. I.e., 'personal_mem pm' and the one after the join a different name 'personal_mem pm2'

Then when you're qualifying your columns in select/where, you can reference the right one in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Alias your first reference of 'personal_mem' to members (it appears you reference 'personal_mem' as members in the joins beneath

```
SELECT personal_mem.id_mem, personal_mem.fn, personal_mem.ln, personal_mem.email,     personal_mem.organisation, personal_mem.city, personal_mem.state, personal_mem.postcode, members.type, members.paid_to_date, members.username, payments_mem.payment_type 
FROM `personal_mem` members 
LEFT JOIN personal_mem ON members.id_mem = personal_mem.id_mem 
LEFT JOIN payments_mem ON members.id_mem = payments_mem.id_mem 
WHERE members.paid_to_date > 1369922400 AND payments_mem.confirmed != 'TRUE' 
ORDER BY payments_mem.payment_type
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the same table twice without an alias.To fix this, you need to use table aliases again for personal_mem. You currently have personal_mem members you can put members2 or pm and pm2 as suggested by the last answer.

```
SELECT personal_mem.id_mem, personal_mem.fn, personal_mem.ln
, personal_mem.email, personal_mem.organisation, personal_mem.city
, personal_mem.state, personal_mem.postcode, members.type, members.paid_to_date
, members.username, payments_mem.payment_type 
FROM `personal_mem` members
LEFT JOIN personal_mem pm ON members.id_mem = pm.id_mem 
LEFT JOIN payments_mem payment ON members.id_mem = payment.id_mem 
WHERE members.paid_to_date > 1369922400 AND payment.confirmed != 'TRUE' 
ORDER BY payment.payment_type
```

I would also suggest using table aliases in the select statement to clean it up.

I also change payments_mem to payment to be consistent.